# How to execute a file like "~/.bashrc" for bash for ash?

Tags: command-line, ash

I have a board with the default shell being `sh`. At the end of "/etc/profile" there is:

```
exec /bin/ash
```

This changes the shell to `ash`.

What should I do if want to execute a file where I defined some aliases in `ash`?

I tried using:

```
exec /bin/ash -f /root/aliases.sh
```

But when I login to the board using `ssh` it exits saying connection closed.

Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `exec /bin/ash -f /root/aliases.sh` `ash` runs non-interactively, and it exits as soon as "/root/aliases.sh" has been executed; that's why the SSH session ends.

So the solution is to run the shell interactively; from [`man 1 ash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ash):

> If the environment variable ENV is set on entry to a shell, or is set in the .profile of a login shell, the shell next reads commands from the file named in ENV. Therefore, a user should place commands that are to be executed only at login time in the .profile file, and commands that are executed for every shell inside the ENV file.

So just set `ENV` in "~/.profile":

```
export ENV=/root/aliases.sh
```

and run the shell interactively:

```
exec /bin/ash
```

*However* notice that:

1. Running `exec /bin/ash` at the end of "~/.profile" will replace *any* shell sourcing "~/.profile" (i.e. *any* login shell) with an `ash` instance;
2. This makes no sense. The correct way to get `ash` as a login shell for an user is to change the login shell for the user, which can be done using `chsh`.

So I *really* suggest you to remove `exec /bin/ash` from "~/.profile" and to change the login shell for the user using `chsh` instead.